# Selecting "child + child" in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need a way to select this outer `div` which has three inner `span`s (div and span are just examples here):

```
<div>
 <span/>
 <span/>
 <span/>
</div>
```

The motivation is to *select an element that has three of specified children*. If it was just one, I could use `div > span`, if I just needed to select the spans (not the outer div), I could use `span + span + span` to select them.

Is something like `div > (span + span + span)` possible? (I've tried the parentheses but it's invalid)

**UPDATE:** Since when "**an element containing a set of elements**" become "**selecting a parent**"? This is *not* a duplicate, moreover, this is *exactly the opposite* of that question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible

Comment: It's even not possible with a single child. `div > span` selects the span, not the div (See [Is there a CSS parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) and [Parent selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)).

Comment: try `div.i_have_3_spans` maybe?

Comment: class, id, data-*, etc...

Comment: An element that contains another element is that other element's parent. That's precisely what the word "parent" means. You're asking for a div that is a parent of three consecutive sibling spans, right?

Comment: @BoltClock thank you, but I know English, don't worry, I know what parent means.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu You need to directly refer to the target, there is no way to make a selector solely based on an element being a parent. Using a class designated for certain divs that have 3 spans is your only recourse unless you use JavaScript.

Comment: Reviewing the close vote, "an element containing children E" is the same as "the parent element of E" for CSS purposes, which is the same as the other question. Sorry!

Answer (score -3):

if you want to select 3rd element within a parent then try this

```
div > span:nth-child(3)
```

if you want to select the div try javascript or jQuery

```
var d = $('div > span:nth-child(3)').closest('div');
d.css('attribute','value');
```

Another way is to put required style in css and assign class to that div using jquery.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's not about selecting the 3rd span, but about selecting a div, if it contains 3 spans.